# Can't get jQuery-UI Modal Dialog to set value on submit

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I've got a jQuery Modal dialog that prompts a user for their OpenID username.  The problem is that I can't get the "Submit" function to set the username properly

```
<script>
    var OpenIDAddress;

    $('.openid_btn').click(function () {
        switch ($(this).text()) {
            case "Google":
                $("#openid_identifier").val("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id");
                break;
            case "Yahoo!":
                $("#openid_identifier").val("http://yahoo.com/");
                break;
            case "myOpenID":
                OpenIDAddress = 'http://{username}.myopenid.com/';
                openOpenIDDialog();
                break;
        }
    });

    // Manages the username window
    $("#openid-username-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Submit': function () {
                OpenIDAddress = OpenIDAddress.replace(/{username}/, $("openid-username").val());
                $("#openid_identifier").val(OpenIDAddress);
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });


    // Opens the Username Input Window
    function openOpenIDDialog() {
        $('#openid-username-dialog').css('display', 'inherit');
        $('#openid-username-dialog').dialog('open');

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Basically what I'm doing is using a case statement to decide which openID the user clicked.

If the openID Provider requires a username, then I open a modal dialog requesting the username.

Then, when the user presses submit, I want to run a regex to replace `{username}` with the users entry.

The problem I'm having is that the when you click submit, I get the following in my input

> http://undefined.myopenid.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FRIGGING SON OF A @#$%^

I forgot to add the hash mark

```
OpenIDAddress = OpenIDAddress.replace(/{username}/, $("openid-username").val());
```

should be

```
OpenIDAddress = OpenIDAddress.replace(/{username}/, $("#openid-username").val());
```